# Human resource allocation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on this application to help the restaurant boss to allocate his staff.

For simplification, consider that we only have part-time staff. Each staff member has a different wage and a different available time (2pm-7pm on Thursday, 7am-9am on Monday, etc).

We divide every day into 12 hours. For every hour we need a different amount of staff (5 staff members during 7am-9am, Sunday; 1 member during 1pm-5pm Monday, etc).

I have a feeling that this is a maximum matching problem, but can't really figure it out. Except for a genetic algorithm, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: [Linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). If you prefer to keep things simple try using the [Simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). If you'd rather go for maximum efficiency try [Karmarkar's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar's_algorithm). You might try asking this question over on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), they might have some other ideas - but to me it smells like Linear Programing. (My particular hammer for this kind of nail, but... :-). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob Jarvis. I will learn it. It's new to me.

Comment: Note that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem is a special case of linear programming for which there are efficient algorithms, and, on the face of it, at least speaks the same vocabulary as your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to answer so if anyone have the same problem as me could have a clue. The fastest and simplest solution I can find is Hungarian algorithm. Every time section is a node. Each staff member divide to k node ( k is their available time). With this model, we just run the Hungarian algorithm and problem solved.